# Correct definition of random variable and (discrete) probability distribution?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, definition

I defined it as follows:

*Let us consider a random variable $X$ defined on a countable sample space $\Omega$ over $K$ possible outcomes, and $P(X)$ its discrete PD defined as the set of probabilities that $X$ takes on the non-zero probability values $x_{i}$ $(i=1,..,C)$ as:
\begin{equation}
P(X=x_{i})=p_{i}=\frac{n_{i}}{N}, \label{Prob}
\end{equation}
with $n_{i}$ the number of events relative to the i-th possible outcome, $N$ the overall number of events or measurements, and $C$ the number of all possible outcomes, such that, in the limit of the large numbers ($N \rightarrow \infty$), for a normalized PD, $\sum_{i} p_{i}=1$.*

What is wrong with the above definition? I was reprimanded for unclear mathematical language. For example, I didn't specify that random variables are measurable functions from the sample space into K. Well, ok, but isn't a random variable a measurable function defined over a (here countable) sample space? Just wondering how to rephrase the whole thing in a correct and/or more rigorous manner?

Comment: What is it that that language is meant to define?

Comment: A discrete probability distribution to use in a context of statistical physics.

Comment: Ok...and what does it mean to say that the $x_i$ are the "non-zero probability values" $X$ can take?

Comment: What you have written is very unclear and seems to only pertain to distributions on finite sets (what is $N$? for example).  Rather than trying to repair it, I suggest looking up one of the standard definitions.

Comment: I didn't write that xi are the "non-zero probability values X can take" but that the discrete PD is defined as the set of probabilities that X takes on the non-zero probability values xi \in X. N is the overall number of events or measurements. That's the kind of standard definition I found.